# How to update a table in postgres to add an order column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I can do a window function like `select *, rank() over (partition by column1 order by column2) from mytable` to get the order of the rows sorted by `column2`. But if I've added a column `order_column` to `mytable`, how can I `UPDATE` that column to include the results of the window function, so that the new `order_column` gets populated with the results?

So it would update all the existing rows in `mytable` but it wouldn't add any new rows.

Comment: post your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably should not be doing this, as your order column is really just data derived from the rest of the table, and it could be invalidated upon the change of any data.  That being said, if you must do this, an update join would be one option:

```
UPDATE mytable AS t1
SET order_column = t2.rnk
FROM
(
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY column1 ORDER BY column2) rnk
    FROM mytable
) t2
WHERE t1.id = t2.id;
```

I assume here that your table has a primary key column `id`.  If the PK be named something else, change the name used in my query.  If your table doesn't have a primary key, then add one.

Comment: Given the window function, it's safe to just join on `column1` and `column2`. Also it should just be `order_column`, not `t1.order_column`.

Comment: @Nick So we don't need to join on an id column?

Comment: @user779159 Given that the rank value is completely determined by `column1` and `column2`, you could join on these 2 columns instead.  But joining on a PK would also work.

Comment: Btw is it not possible to use `USING` when joining with a subquery even if the join column names are identical? When can you use `USING`?